# IP SLA with follow on actions

Tags: ip, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

Good day, 
I have an odd one here. I am wanting to run an IP SLA to ping another device in the network, and if it stops responding, or the interface goes into a down state. I would like it to run a shut, no shut on the interface.

I have found multiple sites saying you can accomplish this through EEM (Event manager), however this is a 2960, which is incapable of EEM.

This is also a temporary switch, which is only being used for imaging workstations.

My question is how to create the SLA to run the commands, when a ping stops responding, or if the interface goes down?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is that a layer-3 interface on the switch?

Comment: I have an vlan operating in L3.

Comment: My question is how to create the SLA to run the commands, when a ping stops responding, or if the interface goes down.     Sorry if I wasn't clear on this.

Comment: How do you intend to relate a layer-2 interface to a layer-3 address?

Comment: The vlan is operating in L3, the switch isn't doing the routing though...... Maybe I didn't clarify the interface is the uplink from the switch. I have to manually intervene on the switch and run a shut, no shut on the interface, to resume communication between the two switches. My need is as follows. If the interface goes down, or if the switch is no longer able to ping it's uplink, run a shut no shut on the physical port.

Comment: Right, but how do you intend to relate a particular layer-2 interface to a layer-3 address. I assume you mean a physical interface, rather than the layer-3 SVI. A layer-2 switch has no idea (and simply doesn't care) which layer-3 addresses are connected to which layer-2 interfaces.

Comment: I also think that this an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/369973). You should ask our help to determine the root cause of your problem. You should not need to perform `shutdown` then `no shutdown` as a regular thing. There is some underlying problem that you should fix. For example, is the interface going to `err-disable`? If so, why?

Comment: While I don't disagree with you about there is a larger issue going on in the switch, this is only for temporary purposes. So spending a couple of hours diagnosing a switch, instead of 15 minutes writing an SLA to shut, no shut a port seems to be more effective. This switch is not destined to be a full production switch, only being used for imaging workstations for the week.    Sorry if I come off as being crass, but it's just the case at this point.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @Krayvyn, you just mentioned that the SW is not doing the routing. If the routing device supports EEM , then you could run the ICMP echo there and further use EEM to telnet to the switch and "shut" and "un shut" the interface

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll try to answer the part about how to "trigger action A when event E happens" on a device where EEM is not supported.

One way to do this would be to run a script on an external computer that has a permanent connection to the switch. This "external computer" can be one of your existing workstations, or a new workstation that you procure for the purpose or maybe even a small single-board computer (like one well-known product in the $5 - $35 price range which I cannot name here :-)) running nothing but the OS and your script.